# Need help for install plugins in mantis

Tags: plugins, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, mantis

I am newbie in mantis bug tracker so may be my question is not that much proper.

I had install MantisBT Version  1.2.15. In that i want to install following plugins

> 1. JabberNotifierSystem
> 2. announce
> 3. MantisGraph
> 4. PastePicture
> 5. XmlImportExport
> 6. timetracking
> 7. Timecard
> 8. Zip-Export

Please find attached image in which i pointed my installed plugins & also mention above listed plugins which i want to install.

Can any one tell me how can i install those plugins?

Any suggestion or help would be appreciate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the plugins from https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins to
   your mantisbt/plugins folder.
2. You may have to change the base folder of the plugin. Refer the README or INSTALL file for the correct folder name.
3. Login to Mantis using the administrator account
4. Visit Manage-->Manage Plugins
5. Install the plugins by clicking the install link Some plugins may require other plugins as dependencies, you can follow the same steps to install them.